# Object is not displaying values in console log

Tags: javascript, class, object, javascript-objects

My class objects are not displaying from the main object in the console log

```
// Inventory , the main class

class Inventory{
    constructor(shoe,customer){
        this.shoes = [];
        this.customers = [];
    }

    addShoes(shoe){
        this.shoes.push(shoe);
    }

    addCustomers(customer){
        this.customers.push(customer);
    }
}

// Customer class

class Customer{
    constructor(name,address,phone){
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;  
        this.phone = phone;
    }
}

//Shoes class

class Shoes{
    constructor(brand,name,color,size){
        this.brand =  brand;
        this.name = name;
        this.colors = [];
        this.sizes = [];
    }

    addColors(color){
        this.colors.push(color);
    }

    addSizes(size){
        this.sizes.push(size);
    }
}

// Where I put in the data for the object values, to display to console log

const inventory = new Inventory();

const myko = new Customer("Myko","216 Peachtree",9144444444);

const shoes = new Shoes("Nike","Air Force 1");
      shoes.addColors(["Black/Green","Blue/white","Red/Blue","White/Red"]);
      shoes.addSizes([12,10,9,11]);


const newAdd = new Inventory(shoes,myko);

console.log(newAdd);
```

---

what my console log displays , empty data

Inventory {shoes: Array(0), customers: Array(0)}
customers: Array(0)

---

I want the console log to display , when I put in the data when I call the Inventory class in console.log

Inventory {shoes: Array(1), customers: Array(1)}

customers: "Myko" , "216 Peachtree" , 9144444444"

shoes:     "Nike", "Air Force 1", "Black/Green", "Blue/white", "Red/Blue", "White/Red", 12, 10, 9, 11

Comment: you're not doing anything with the arguments passed to the `Inventory` constructor

Answer (score 1):

You didn't initiallize the inventory with the parameter in the constructor. ([] instead.)

```js
class Inventory{
    constructor(shoe,customer){
        this.shoes = shoe;
        this.customers = customer;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked.  I cant believe it was something that simple, lol.